# Connecting more than one workstation to chef server

Tags: chef

can I connect more than one workstation to the server at a time. Because whenever I try to connect a new workstation to server,it generates a new pair of keys . hence the previous workstation losses its connection with server.
and When I used the same pair of keys for another workstation then it shows error.
So how to connect more than one workstation to chef server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, many administrators can interact with the Chef server.
Are you creating a new user through the web interface or `knife user create` (using the credentials of the first user)? The emitted key is the one for the second admin and this should not influence the first at all.

Comment: I used this site to connect workstation to server- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-chef-server-workstation-and-client-on-ubuntu-vps-instances

Comment: Okay. All the regeneration of the keys should be only done for the already existent *admin* user. For additional users, just go to `User > Create`.